# meteor js change hostname

Tags: node.js, meteor

I want to run meteor js server on a different host name. just like virtual hosts in xampp..

by default it runs on http://localhost:3000/

I want it to run on http://meteor.trivia.com:3000

both are local domains

I have tried to set ROOT_URL like that:
set ROOT_URL=http://meteor.trivia.com:3000 meteor

and then to run meteor, but it crashes...

I have tried to set the hosts file and create a virtual host with proxy like that:

```
<VirtualHost meteor.trivia.com:3000>
    ServerName meteor.trivia.com

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

it worked, but the application still thinks it is on localhost.

Meteor.absoluteUrl();   is "localhost"

I am using windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for unix, it's just:

`ROOT_URL=http://meteor.trivia.com:3000 meteor` (no "set" at the beginning)

---

if using windows:

`set ROOT_URL=http://meteor.trivia.com:3000` (no "meteor" at the end)

and then, in a separate command:

`meteor`

Comment: so it should be only `set ROOT_URL=http://meteor.trivia.com:3000`, without the "meteor" at the end. that's intended to set the variable and run a command right away (`meteor` in this case) on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

open with nodepad: c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

add host the host

127.0.0.1   your.hostname.com

in cmd:

set ROOT_URL=http://meteor.trivia.com:3000

then run meteor